# Turning on the light

Tags: word-usage

Do younger Japanese people really use 電気をつける to mean "turn on the light"? It sounds like something that your Grandad would say in the times when electricity was new and exciting. I know it's taught in textbooks but they can have a tendency to be somewhat anachronistic. Is it the most common phrase, and if not what should I be saying?

Comment: You know, we still say 洋服 even though nobody practically wears 和服 today...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's the most normal way to say it, among young people too.

> 電気をつける - Turn on the lights
>   電気を消す - Turn off the lights

If you don't like it then [明かりをつける（消す）](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12118843782) is another phrase you could use...

Comment: I think it's a great phrase. I just worried it might be old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

Ash's answer is correct. Those phrases are used maybe 95% of the time.　The other 5% is business/formal phrasing, using 点灯、消灯